# удалить элемент через 2 секунды после появления в DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не работает, в чем проблема?

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  $('#yikes-mailchimp-container-1 > p').on("DOMNodeInserted", function (event) { 
          setTimeout(function(e) {        //2. Receive the element in variable o
            document.querySelector("#yikes-mailchimp-container-1 > p").outerHTML = "";
          }, 2000, e);    
   });
});
```

Comment: не определена переменная `e` - посмотри консоль, в ней должна быть ошибка `ReferenceError`

Answer (score 3):

В данном коде

```
setTimeout(function(e) {        //2. Receive the element in variable o
  document.querySelector("#yikes-mailchimp-container-1 > p").outerHTML = "";
}, 2000, e);
```

Идет попытка использовать переменную `e`, которая не была объявлена. Из-за этого происходит ошибка.

Достаточно убрать ненужный параметр:

```
setTimeout(function() {        //2. Receive the element in variable o
  document.querySelector("#yikes-mailchimp-container-1 > p").outerHTML = "";
}, 2000);
```

Comment: не помогает, вдимо нужно делать через  MutationObserver

Comment: let iza = setInterval(function() {
    if (document.querySelector("#yikes-mailchimp-container-1 p")){
        var elem = document.querySelector("#yikes-mailchimp-container-1 p");
   elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
        clearInterval(iza);
    }
}, 3000);

Comment: так работает, но нужно через обсервер переделывать